# R: transparent colors using colorRampPalette

Tags: r, colors, plot, transparency

I have the following code that draws arrows with a gradient:

```
csa <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2,first.col,second.col,length=0.15, ...) {
  cols <- colorRampPalette( c(first.col,second.col))(250)
  x <- approx(c(0,1),c(x1,x2), xout=seq(0,1,length.out=251))$y
  y <- approx(c(0,1),c(y1,y2), xout=seq(0,1,length.out=251))$y

  arrows(x[250],y[250],x[251],y[251], col=cols[250],length=length, ...)
  segments(x[-251],y[-251],x[-1],y[-1],col=cols, ...)

}

color.scale.arrow <- Vectorize(csa, c('x1','y1','x2','y2') )

# Create sample data
x <- c(1,3,5,3,2,1,6,2)
y <- c(2,5,3,7,2,1,5,6)

x1 <- c(1,3,5,3)
y1 <- c(2,5,3,7)
x2 <- c(2,1,6,2)
y2 <- c(2,1,5,6)

# Plot sample data
plot(x,y, main='')
color.scale.arrow(x1,y1,x2,y2,'#5F9EA0','#CD3333',lwd=2)
```

Which produced this Figure:

[image]

I want to make these lines transparent, but simply adding 50 to the colour code (i.e. proportion of transparency = 50%) does not work unfortunately:

```
# Plot sample data (transparent?)
plot(x,y, main='')
color.scale.arrow(x1,y1,x2,y2,'#5F9EA050','#CD333350',lwd=2)
```

Any idea why this doesn't work, and how to make these lines transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add the transparency after you generate the gradient, not before. You'll need to do this within your `csa` function, so consider adding an `alpha` argument to both `csa` and `color.scale.arrow`. Assuming you have done so, you can add the alpha transparency to the color gradient after generating it:

```
cols <- colorRampPalette( c(first.col,second.col))(250)
cols <- paste0(cols, alpha)
```

Also worth noting the alpha transparency is also hexadecimal: so `"50"` is not 50%, `"7f"` is.

Comment: This does not work for my example data unfortunately... I just copied and pasted your line there after the plot(x,y, main='') command, and also tried that line with "7f" instead of 50, but I keep getting the same plot (with no transparency). Am I missing something?

Comment: You would have to do this to `cols` in `csa()`